# Why is Xcode thinking my variable is returning an NSURL when it should be returning an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios6

I get the following warning: "Incompatible pointer types assigning NSString from NSURL".

Here's the code in question:

```
cell.articleURL.text = [self.articles[row] URL];
```

I'm assigning a label the value of an Article object's URL property. The self.articles array is only used to hold Article objects.

In the Article class I have this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *URL;
```

Why is it thinking it's an NSURL?

Comment: do you have a method called URL, which returns NSURL?

Comment: Well, that's just long-hand for `self.articles[row].URL` but since `self.articles[row]` returns an ID I had to use the method. I guess it's the get method.

Comment: You can cast the output of `self.articles[row]` to the proper class and then the compiler will be happy with either notation.

Comment: But I still wonder, from where a method URL is called, as he doesn't have that method, and neither cocoa/touch framework have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `self.articles[row]` will be returning an object of type `id`, which means that the Objective-C runtime can't figure out which method implementation applies.  It's finding a `URL` method in another interface and using that one.

There's more information about this problem in the article [A big weakness in Objective-C's weak typing](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2011/06/big-weakness-of-objective-c-weak-typing.html) by Matt Gallagher.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.articleURL.text = [self.articles[row] URL];
```

As you said `self.articles[row]` returns `id`, so you need to enforce its type to be `Article`.

```
cell.articleURL.text = [(Article *)self.articles[row] URL];
```

you have a method called URL that is getting called by the object returned by `self.articles[row]` and its return type is `NSURL`

As I can not find any class having a method called `URL`, then this must be there in any of the frameworks or classes / library you are using and it is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code to avoid the confusion:

```
Article *article = self.articles[0];
cell.articleURL.text = article.URL;
```

As Jim stated, the compiler is finding the wrong `URL` method for the `id` object. By splitting up the code, you avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't know the return type of your array and so guesses which method from which class you might be calling. You need to add a cast like so, which lets the compiler know exactly which class to expect:

```
cell.articleURL.text = [(Article *) self.articles[row] URL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Jim answer.  You will need to cast the result of `[self.articles[row]]` to the correct class where `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *URL;` is declared.  So the Objective-C runtime can figure out which method implementation can be applied.

i.e.

```
[(Article *)[self.articles[row]] URL]
```

Or store this in a variable of type `Article`, then call URL on that object.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an `NSMutableArray` at that time compiler don't know that for what type of object you will store. It is decided dynamically. So when you are trying to get `URL` from 
`[self.articles[row] URL];` compiler treats it as id type. So you have to use type cast `cell.articleURL.text = [(Article *) self.articles[row] URL];`